# "Important updates installed" keeps popping up

Tags: debian, notifications, software-updates

Since a few weeks, I get a notification after each boot telling me that important updates has been installed. Even if I dismiss it then immediately reboot, it comes again. It starts to be quite annoying.

It looks like it has started after I get a message asking me something like rebooting for installing updates (sorry, I do not remember precisely). I have done that, though not being used to it at all.

I am under Debian Jessie 8.7. My box is configured to run unattended upgrades, and it works fine since I have set it up. (That was when latest Jessie was 8.5.) It is shut down every day.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the file

```
/var/lib/PackageKit/offline-update-competed
```

solves it.

Solution found on Debian forum [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=121809#p586530). It looks like it is a [known bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785437).

But it seems to be there since at least two years. And so it may happen again eventually. I hope someone knows a better solution.

(And yes by the way, there is [a typo in the file name](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-December/msg03984.html).)

Follow-up: I am no more having this issue, but I am no more acting on updates notification nor select the "install update" option when shutting down. I just let unattended-upgrade do the job instead. It sounds to me as a reliable way to avoid the trouble.

Comment: nice catch, that one about the typo is priceless